# How do I create a Google Cloud Function to compare data within multiple Firestore collections?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am developing an application which tracks user GPS locations and stores those locations within a Firebase Firestore collection.

The application is written in Swift and has features which (for security/privacy reasons) assign a 6-character randomized ID to each user/device. An example of a randomized ID would be: FITdGQ

When a user signs in to the application for the first time, a Firestore collection is created which is named the same as the user's randomized ID. In this example I will continue to use FITdGQ.

When a user's location is logged by the application, a record is created within that user's Firestore collection. (ex. "FITdGQ\newrecordID") The new record uses an application generated ID which consists of a POSIX/UNIX epoch time interval in the format: 1609791289.36167. This time interval translates to "Monday, January 4, 2021 1:14:49.361 PM GMT-07:00"

Within this new record (FITdGQ\1609791289.36167) we store the following data:

```
    date: "Jan 4, 2021 at 1:14:49 PM"

    description: "7979 S Garrison Ct, 7979 S Garrison Ct, Littleton, CO 80128, United States @ <+39.57250484,-105.10191173> +/- 100.00m, region CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<+39.57250565,-105.10187950> radius 23.25', center:<+39.57250565,-105.10187950>, radius:23.25m)"

    id: "FITdGQ"

    latitude: 39.572504838034114

    longitude: -105.10191173302485
```

The date is the plain-text translation of the document ID.

The description is the plain-text 2D coordinates for the recorded location. It defines a circular region of +/- 100 meters wherein the location record was created.

The id is the encoded device identifier for the app. This ID should be used to distinguish the document from other documents created by other users.

The latitude and longitude are the user's exact location at time the location was recorded.

The following picture shows the exact structure of data that I am referring to in this question.

[image: The Firestore data structure]

A new record is added every time a user changes locations and remains in the new location for at least 10 minutes. This happens for every user of the app.

What I would like to do is create a Google Cloud Function that compares the documents contained in every collection within Firestore against all the other documents created by other users.

This comparison (as I see it working, but I'm open to suggestions) should get a list of every collection within Firestore that had changes within the past 24 hours. Once the list is generated, the function should compare every record looking for similar coordinates and timestamp data. The timestamp data should be within ten minutes of each other, with the epoch being the older of the timestamps. If a match is found, the function should create a record which lists 1) the ID of each device involved, 2) the location description from the record, 3) the timestamp of the record. This data can than be used by other applications for correlating when, where and who was at a particular location at the same time.

Example: User FITdGQ was at 7979 S Garrison Ct, Littleton, CO 80128 on January 4th, 2021 at 14:18:51 and User CPfbFw was also at 7979 S Garrison Ct, Littleton, CO 80128 on January 4th, 2021 at 14:08:59

The function should recognize that FITdGQ and CPfbFw were at the same location within the same ten minute period and generate a record which indicates this.

I'm unfamiliar with how to accomplish this in TypeScript, which from what I understand is the required language on Google Cloud Functions. Is there anyone who can provide some insight and advice?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project. A couple of things - it is commonplace to use the users uid to associate data with the user. e.g. what's the use case of creating a separate 6 digit random code when you already have one with the uid? Second question: is the 'big picture' here to show a user other users that are within a certain radius of them?

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for taking the time to respond. This project falls under the mantle of a contact tracing application. We are implementing a distributed simulation infection model (https://github.com/viratrace/InfectionModel/) that we created to assess user risk in near-realtime. The problem that we have is GDPR and HIPPA compliance for privacy and security of user data. Most users refuse to use an application that has any way of identifying them personally so the solution to that is to have a random device identifier (6 character code) converted into a fake email address within the app itself.

Comment: In this case, the user's email address is "FITdGQ@ble.app". This email is used to enable Firebase authentication without collecting personally identifying information. We use the UID within Firebase to associate the randomized device identifier with a particular user and will also use it for certain messaging functions, etc.

Comment: I see. Firestore and Google Cloud Identity (Firebase Authentication) is HIPPA compliant at this point, but I can see where users would be sensitive considering the situation. My other question was about proximity. Have you looked into [Geofirestore](https://geofirestore.com)? It makes working with location data and radii very straightforward.

Comment: I've looked at that briefly, but haven't implemented at this time. We are looking at enabling similar features so I think it will not be long before we do. That being said, we are still looking for a way to pre-process the data as I described and then feed it into our model for processing.

Comment: Can you include some code of what you've attempted so we can see what you're stuck on? SO is for coding specific issues so we can help with existing code but crafting the code for you is beyond the scope of what we do here. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post some code and we'll take a look!